# Are these programmatically generated pages a correct SEO approach?

Tags: seo, url, duplicate-content

I am presently working on a taxi booking website. As a test case, the website (which is not yet online) can presently take bookings from 20 cities and booking can be made for 626 destinations (cities) in the country. The booking page (example.com/index.jsp) contains 2 dropdowns (one for origin and other for destination), a date selector and one submit button.

In order to improve my website visibility in Google I have planned to create pages which have (programmatically generated) links as follows:

```
example.com/origin1-to-destination1-taxi
example.com/origin1-to-destination2-taxi
.
.
.
example.com/origin1-to-destination626-taxi
example.com/origin2-to-destination1-taxi
example.com/origin2-to-destination2-taxi
.
.
.
example.com/origin2-to-destination626-taxi
```

and so on …

These pages essentially link to booking page (albeit with different dynamically created title and meta description and of course different URL [using servlet filter]) with different values of the origin and destination dropdowns. The page title, description and values of origin and destination are being added using JSP scriptlets.

**Will this approach help me with SEO? Or does it qualifies as a duplicate content thereby inviting SEO penalties?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a textbook case of keyword stuffed doorway pages generated by script.  It would be disallowed by any search engine rules I have ever seen, on several counts.  Sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but I don't recommend this.

Comment: We are here to set the record straight for some of these folks. I would rather be the bearer of bad news and tell them the truth than perpetuate a bad thing. There is sooooooo much bad SEO junk out there, it drives me nuts! Cheers!!